Does anyone still have a clean shot of our old logo?
Since moving to the new site layouts, we've lost our old brick logo. I've finally found the time and inclination to update my own avatar image to a cleaner, crisper one, and I'd like to drop on the Bricks logo for SO/SE at least.
I'll recreate it if not, but wanted to save myself 5 minutes.
All in all, this will teach me to not save out my original sources.

I'm not sure I understand which logo you are looking for. Is it this one? https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/bricks/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png

Cheers, yeah, that will do - I was after the blue on white like you can see on my profile pic, but I can work with that :)

I see. I don't have the white one anywhere.
